# How to do a consistency check (in relationship) when creating a relation schema for ER diagram

Tags: sql, constraints, entity-relationship

I'm creating an relation schema for my ER diagram and I wonder what the best way is to create constraints against wrong genders being in wrong teams. The ER diagram is shown below.

I do not want female contestants to be able to be member of a male team and likewise I do not want male teams competing in female events. But I want the possibility to have unisex teams that allows both female and male contestants and likewise I want events to have the possibility of being unisex.

[image]

The relevant tables I have created thus far look like this

```
contestants((contestantID), firstName, lastName, height_cm, weight_kg, nationality, PB, gender)
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS “contestants” CASCADE;
CREATE TYPE gender AS ENUM(‘men’, ‘women’, ‘n/a’)
CREATE TABLE “contestants” (
    “contestantID” integer NOT NULL,
    “firstName” VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    “lastName” VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    “height_cm” integer,
    “weight_kg” integer,
    “nationality” VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    “PB” VARCHAR(255),
    “gender” gender NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT “contestantID_pkey” PRIMARY KEY (“contestantID”)
);

MemberOf((contestantID), (teamID))
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS “memberOf” CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE “memberOf” (
    “contestantID” integer REFERENCES contestants(contestantID)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    “teamID” integer REFERENCES teams(teamID)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT “integrity” CHECK (((contestantID NOTNULL) AND (teamID NOTNULL))),
    CONSTRAINT “pkey” PRIMARY KEY (“contestantID”, “teamID”)
);

competeIn((teamID), (eventID)) 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS “competeIn” CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE “competeIn” (
    “teamID” integer REFERENCES teams(teamID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    “eventID” integer REFERENCES events(eventID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT “integrity” CHECK ((teamID NOTNULL) AND (eventID NOTNULL)),
    CONSTRAINT “pkey” PRIMARY KEY (“teamID”, “eventID”)
);

teams((teamID),country, teamGender)
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS “teams” CASCADE;
CREATE TYPE gender AS ENUM(‘men’, ‘women’, ‘unisex’, ‘n/a’)
CREATE TABLE “teams” (
    “teamID” integer NOT NULL,
    “teamGender” gender NOT NULL,
    “country” VARCHAR(3) NOTNULL,
    CONSTRAINT “teamID_pkey” PRIMARY KEY (“teamID”) 
);

events((eventID), group, round, class, eventGender)
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS “events” CASCADE;
CREATE TYPE gender AS ENUM(‘men’, ‘women’, ‘unisex’, ‘n/a’)
CREATE TABLE “events” (
    “eventID” integer NOT NULL,
    “group” VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    “round” integer,
    “class” VARCHAR(255),
    “eventGender” gender NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT “events_pkey” PRIMARY KEY (“eventID”)
);
```

I'm think about somehow putting constraints in relationships but atm I'm not really certain. Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: looks like you need implement some triggers for insert/update. There you can handle the bussines logic and restriction and raise proper error message if occurs.

Comment: Thanks didn't think about trigger functions!